# How to join multiple dataframes within a loop using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have 3 tables on each excel sheet: sheet1 - `Gross`, sheet2 - `Margin`, sheet3 - `Revenue`

So I was able to iterate through each sheet and unpivot it.

But how can I join them together?

[image]

```
    sheet_names = ['Gross','Margin','Revenue']

    full_table = pd.DataFrame()
    for sheet in sheet_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(BudgetData.xlsx', sheet_name = sheet, index=False)
        unpvt = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Company'], var_name ='Month', value_name = sheet)
# how can I join unpivoted dataframes here?
        print(unpvt)
```

[image]

**Desirable result:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @Celius Stingher. 
I think this is what I need. It just gives me weird sorting:

[image]

and gives me this warning:

```
Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
```

Comment: Do you actually want to join them (as in join) or append/concatenate them?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python. I guess I should say concatenate them. Thanks

Comment: Yes I understood the question now. I'll answer it in a min, if it helps you solve it, feel free to accept my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems you are doing the pivoting but not saving each unpivoted dataframe anywhere. Let's create a list of dataframes, that will store each unpivoted dataframe. Later, we will pass that list of dataframes as argument for the `pd.concat` function to perform the concatenation.

```
sheet_names = ['Gross','Margin','Revenue']
list_of_df = []
full_table = pd.DataFrame()
for sheet in sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(BudgetData.xlsx', sheet_name = sheet, index=False)
    df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Company'], var_name ='Month', value_name = sheet)
    list_of_df.append(df)

full_df = pd.concat(list_of_df,ignore_index=True)
full_df = full_df.sort_values(['Company','Month'])
print(full_df)
```

### Edit:

Now that I understand what you need, let's try a different approach. After the loop try the following code instread of the `pd.concat`:

```
full_df = list_of_df[0].merge(list_of_df[1],on=['Company','Month']).merge(list_of_df[2],on=['Company','Month'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont have df1, df2, df3. I am looping through each excel sheet and writing it into unptv

Comment: Do  I need to iterate through each daraframe?

Comment: Oh okay, then you should change it a bit the code. I'll show you in a minute

Comment: Try the code below the edit, it should be functional to your issue.

Comment: Thanks. It gives me result with a lot of NULL value. I am trying to find out why

Comment: It shouldn't if the data you are showing is the only you are working with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206888/discussion-between-celius-stingher-and-serdia).

Comment: So if I use `full_df = pd.concat(list_of_df,axis=1, sort=False)` it gives me what I need except I have columns Company and Month for each Gross, Margin and Revenue

Answer (score 1):

A pd.concat will just pile everything together, you want to actually merge the DataFrames using pd.merge. This works similarly to a SQL Join statement. (based on the 'desired' image in your post)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

you just want to use a list of columns to merge on. If you get them all into tidy data frames with the same names as your sheets you would want to do something like:

```py
gross.merge(margin, on=['Company', 'Month']).merge(revenue, on=['Company', 'Month'])
```